# When vectors go in a cycle pattern

Tags: linear-algebra

If a combination of vectors, say $AB+DC+FG$ form a pattern that looks something like this:

[image]

Does it mean that the outcome is the 0 vector? Bonus: Is there a way to denote this empty vector, much like you denote an empty set $ \emptyset $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the result of the addition is 0, and this vector is sometimes denoted as $\vec{o}$ or $\vec{0}$.

Comment: You could also name that vector $\vec{XX}$ for any point $X$.